# Issues Replacing underscores to hyphens with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Although I already saw few posts about this thema, I am still having some problems to achieve what I want.
My old URL's were like:

```
http://myhostname.com/offer/1234_Nice_Offer_Cool_Whatever_HEllyeah.htm
```

And obviously I want to rewrite them to:

```
http://myhostname.com/offer/1234-nice-offer-cool-whatever-hellyeah.htm
```

This is the code I tried in .htaccess. This works fine to replace the underscores in URL's which they don't have ANY directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.htm$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes,N] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, this paire of rules work fine with URL's like:

```
http://myhostname.com/1234_Some_Section_hellyeah.htm
```

But when I try the same code for URL's like:

```
http://myhostname.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/1234_Some_Offer_Or_Section.htm
```

Then, the server makes an infinite loop (I figure of the [N] flag...)
Basically, I would like to know in which way affects a per-directory URL to these rules and why am I getting this infinite loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need N flag. To replace underscore by hyphen recursively following code will work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)_(.+?\.htm)$ $1-$2 [L,NC,E=underscores:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm I have posted it after extensive testing. Does your version of Apache support env variables?

Comment: I figure so, because testing with other rules worked. My version is Apache/2.2.16. I think we don't need the [L] flag on the first line. I tried your rules as well with this emulator http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: That emulator is only for very basic testing. Do you get 404 in browser or some other error?

Comment: The rules make a recursive redirection til the entire URL is replaced. That means that for strings of more than 10 words length, apache shows a 500 error. This is easily configurable through the "LimitInternalRecursion" param. I don't get why the second rule is never executed.This is my $_SERVER variable: `[REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_underscores] => Yes
    [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_underscores] => Yes
    [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200`
Which looks like on the last iteration, the variable underscores is lost.

Comment: redirection limit will be hit if there are more than 10 underscores in the URL (highly unlikely). I spent enormous time on finding a solution for this and original `N` flag even caused my Apache hog all the CPU and caused and then I had to hard boot my MacBook. Not sure why env variable isn't working for you. Try adding `R` flag in first rule to see what you get.

Comment: Sorry about your troubles! I think I found where the problem is. Everytime that a RewriteRule is applied, mod_rewrite applies again the entire .htaccess to the modified URL, right? So, on the last iteration, we have already the URL like test-test-test.htm, which means that on the next iteration (or Internal Redirect according to Apache) the underscores variable is not set. Am I right? If so, how can I force the 301 redirect after many mod_rewrite "Internal Redirects"? Thank you @anubhava!

Comment: Actually after replacing very last underscore env variable should be set and `RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]` should be executed immediately. Can you try in a different browser or try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: I tried many times with different browsers, and the behavior was the same. Having a look into the `rewrite.log`, looks like mod_rewrite make an internal redirect RIGHT AFTER applying a RewriteRule, which means that on the next iteration underscores is not set. Rewrite log order:
`applying pattern '^([^_]+)_(.+?\.htm)$' to uri 'offer/707_test_test.htm'
**internal redirect**
 applying pattern '^([^_]+)_(.+?\.htm)$' to uri 'offer/707-test_test.htm'
**internal redirect** `

Comment: Ok, Try adding `R` flag in first rule to see what you get.

Comment: Got it! On every iteration, mod_rewrite is carrying the environment varibales as REDIRECT_VARNAME, so I changed your condition from `RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$` to `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_underscores} ^Yes$` THANK YOU very much @anubhava!

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out eventually for you.