# remove unwanted characters from url using htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

in my recent project, rewrite rule is working fine but problem is that i am not able to remove unwanted characters from the url. Below is the htaccess code :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com\.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /find\.php\?source=([^\s&]+)&destination=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1-to-%2.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)-to-([^\s]+)?.html$ find.php?source=$1&destination=$2 [L,QSA]
```

input is
    find.php?source=Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India&destination=Gurgaon, Haryana, India

and output is :
    http://domain.com/Noida%2C+Uttar+Pradesh%2C+India-to-Gurgaon%2C+Haryana%2C+India.html

I just want to remove %2C and + from url and want to replace them to this - so that output url will be :-

```
http://domain.com/Noida-Uttar-Pradesh-India-to-Gurgaon-Haryana-India.html
```

Comment: Try this it may help [Url Rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741708/issues-replacing-underscores-to-hyphens-with-htaccess)

Comment: Arun, can u suggest me a simple way coz i am beginner in htaccess rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# replace all comma by underscore
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:,|%2C)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1_%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# replace all space by hyphen
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# redirect long URL to a pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /find\.php\?source=([^\s&]+)&destination=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-to-%2.html? [R=302,L,NE]

# route pretty URL an actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)-to-([^\s]+)?.html$ find.php?source=$1&destination=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: anubhava, i would like to ask one more thing, if i am applying this code my original values are modified by htaccess like delhi, india is now delhi-india when i access with the help of $_GET, can i have original value.

Comment: is it possible to convert all comma by underscore and all space by hyphen from your first line.

Comment: no it's not working, also note anubhava my browser converting all comma by %2C, but u r using %20.

Comment: See updated code. It redirected: `http://domain.com/find.php?source=Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India&destination=Gurgaon, Haryana, India` to `http://domain.com/Noida_-Uttar-Pradesh_-India-to-Gurgaon_-Haryana_-India.html`

Comment: YES, it worked, thanks anubhava for your help. can you suggest me good source to study about htaccess.

Comment: You can use http://askapache.com website. Also you may now mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: that is really a good source to learn, thanks anubhava and also i have marked your answer as accepted.