# url rewrite issue not being solved

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have done lot of study to learn htaccess but nothing fits in head (don't know why). Done quite searching/googling to solve this but nothing fruitful found hence posting here considering one time activity.

I have this dynamic url (fix params count) which keeps on changing as per user inputs:

```
http://domain.com/Results.php?keyword=+Operations%2C+Facility%2C+Sales%2C+Strategy%2C+MIS%2C++Analytics%2C+&Location=Delhi%2C+Noida%2C+Gurgaon%2C+&exp=6&functional_area=1004&Industry=10008&salary=118&Search_jobs=Search+Jobs
```

I want to change this dynamic url to something like this:

```
http://domain.com/Operations-Facility-Sales-Strategy-MIS-Analytics-in-Delhi-Noida-Gurgaon
```

while googling i found [this_url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480477) which remove all comma, spaces etc but didn't served the purpose considering following conditions i need to meet.

**Conditions:**

1. original url query strings should be accessible to Results.php
   script
2. url length should be short/decent as per SEO guidelines
3. if more than one space, trim it to one space
4. display re-write url only for keywords and location name only
5. all other files/scripts should not be impacted with revised url

**EDIT**

i had used above mentioned link htaccess to my server & managed to achieve following (My current url)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# replace all comma by hyphen
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:,|%2C)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# replace all space by hyphen
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP 
[NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# tried this one to achieve some result but not worked
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-
zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)?.php$ Results.php?keyword=$1&
Location=$2&exp=$2&functional_area=$4&Industry=$5&salary=$6&
Search_jobs=$7 [L,QSA]
```

Now problem is to remove all query strings & append only revised url of "Keyword" and "Location" params to achieve following result. Any help.

**My current URL**

```
http://domain.com/Results.php?keyword=Operation-Manager-FACILITY-MANAGER-
3D-Animator-and-Compositor&Location=Rest-Andaman-Nicobar-Rest-Andhra-
Pradesh-Delhi-NCR&exp=&functional_area=&Industry=&salary=&
Search_jobs=Search-Jobs
```

**Required URL**

```
http://domain.com/Operation-Manager-FACILITY-MANAGER-3D-Animator-
and-Compositor-in-Rest-Andaman-Nicobar-Rest-Andhra-
Pradesh-Delhi-NCR
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Marcos for referring to link. Though i strongly believe in self learning in stead of asking questions, but will take care in future.

Comment: You are welcome, but stackoverflow is not a learning site, is to help another people to solve specific problems. If you ask for `1) i want this, 2) and this, 3) and this` but you don't make some effort to achieve by yourself, the most common result is that your questions will be closed without answers. Try to make something by yourself and when you have a problem ask us specifically by that problem. Good luck.